# Exposing data as XML and JSON in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to understand how I can expose my data in XML and JSON. I have made HTML views for the data now, but I don't understand much of the respond_to block and how you can respond with JSON and XML....and at the same time have control on the structure. Can somebody please help me with where I should start reading and learn how to do this? I haven't had much luck searching for it myself.

Answer (score 2):

You can start by reading [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render). It gives a pretty good idea of how rendering works in rails.

[This article](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2009/08/embracing-rest-with-mind-body-and-soul/) is also very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I use the rabl gem to format the JSON I expose.

Your respond_to block for your users_controller#show action could look like:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json
end
```

Then you can create a rabl template in /app/views/users/show.json.rabl:

```
object @user
attributes :id, :username, :first_name, :last_name
```

You can find more about rabl [here](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/)